# When are complementisers implied, but not present, and when are they actually not present?

Tags: syntax, phrase-structure, relative-clauses

I have recently been learning about complementisers and relative clauses etc. and how they relate to x-bar theory. It is a feature of English that some complementisers are optional, especially in spoken English, e.g. "I think (that) you are great".

This is also true for relative clauses: "The person (that) I saw yesterday"; "The ball (that is) on the table".

However, sometimes they are not optional: "The dog that is red" --> *"The dog red".

I suppose what I mean is, **is there a way of telling when "that is" is a not-present optional complementiser, and when it is actually not present?**

For example, with one of the above sentences, is "that is" really implied in the NP, "The ball on the table", or is it simply not there at all?

More particularly, with adjectives like 'available':

"The bread available in the bakery looks delicious".

Does this sentence contain an implied "that is", i.e. it is really a contracted way of saying "The bread THAT IS available in the bakery looks delicious", or does it actually not contain or imply at all "that is"?

This relates to x-bar theory, or rather phrase structure rules, in that normally adjective phrases are not allowed to come after a noun (except in poetic usage etc.), so if "available in the bakery" is an adjective phrase (not a relative clause), why can it come after the noun "bread"?

[in this question I have assumed that "that is" is a complementiser just like "that"; I admit I am not totally sure about this]

Thanks

Comment: Look up [_Whiz_-Deletion](https://www.google.com/search?q=whiz+deletion). _That_ can serve as a relative pronoun, like _which_ or _who_, and _Whiz_-Deletion deletes the subject and initial _be_ of relative clauses like _which is on the table_ into the post nominal modifiers like _the book on the table_. Historically, the _that_ of relative clauses used to be a complementizer, but in relative clauses it's filled every possible role of _wh_-words, except that it can't be used in non-restrictive relatives, and it can't be pied-piped -- those are fates reserved for _wh_-words.

Comment: “The ball on the table” is just a DP with a PP adjunct, you need to be careful with *be*. You may enjoy Dwight Bolinger’s book *That’s that*, where he shows that there are often nuanced differences between the sentences with overt and covert complementizer.

Comment: @jlawler _Whiz deletion_ is just giving a term to the phenomenon being asked about. The question is, essentially, how do you tell whether a noun + post-modifier phrase is an instance of whiz deletion or not? Do you consider all post-modifiers to be whiz-deletions (in which case you’d be contradicting @Keelan)? How do you tell the difference between a whiz-deleted (and therefore on the surface nonexistent) relativiser + copula and a phrase that actually has no relativiser + copula at all?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet that's an interesting question and I'll think about it. The interesting cases would be the ones where relativization is impossible. What are some? If there aren't any then why bother to distinguish, except by rule? Plus, I enjoy all of Bolinger's work, but I don't think his nuances distinguish between real and unreal absence.

Comment: @jlawler The only cases I can think off offhand where relativisation appears impossible to me are what you might call opposites to “*The dog red” – that is, where relativisation is mandatory with regular adjectives because most adjectives cannot post-modify (nor, apparently, whiz-delete), it is blocked with postpositive adjectives: courts [*that are] martial, attorney [*that is] general, spaghetti [*that is] bolognese. Perhaps those pronouns that mandate post-modification are also a case, since _only_ the potentially whiz-deleted forms are possible there: someone nice / *nice someone.

Comment: I think that argues the other way. Going from obligatory to optional is a natural evolution.

Comment: So far, then, after 32 minutes per the SE clock, the null hypothesis has to be that Whiz deletion is available for postnominal modification -- i.e, ideally, there is a 1-1 relation between grammatical postnominal modifiers and relative clauses with dummy _that/wh-_ + _be_ leadins. Exceptions are of extreme interest.

Comment: @jlawler Well, it's not a biconditional relationship, because in the other direction many relative clauses cannot be reduced (essentially, those ones which would result in phrases which cannot postmodify nouns). So we cannot reduce "panda that was ill" or"panda who was a mathematician", for example.

Comment: Because those are one-word modifiers, not modifiers of more than one word. The null hypothesis is that relative clauses are the full expansions of modifiers, and they get reduced as needed by several processes until they decay to one-word status and precede. Like matter around a black hole.

Comment: @jlawler But how about "the panda who was the first animal mathematician to win the Fields medal"? Why does that not work?

Comment: _The man who was the first linguist on the Moon_ is grammatical, if verbose. And whiz deletion doesn't work, granted. But why should it? The NP has been extended by clefting on an unnecessary _man who was_ instead of just saying _the first linguist on the Moon_, so shortening it is silly. Pick one, longer or shorter, but not both. Similarly for panda mathematicians; if you want to cram that much info into one noun phrase, don't go around busting seams.

Comment: @jlawler Can you WD *any* relative clause which has a predicate NP?

Comment: @Araucaria-him Dunno. Ain't tried them all. Can you? But as I said, that hasta be the null hypothesis.

Comment: @jlawler Devil's advocating a bit more, (or testing the null hypothesis further) how about long predicate adjective phrases that don't have any post-head dependents? eg. *I want to be examined by the professor who was very cautiously optimistic*

Comment: _The_? Why complicate your examples? Note, also *_He was examined by a professor very cautiously optimistic_. But _a very cautiously optimistic professor_ is fine. No reason for whizzing if the whole thing can snuggle up pre-N.